# AngularJS not successfully imported

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      
  </head>
    
  <body>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
  </body>
    
</html>
```

I've got this code above. However, when I run it on http-server {{name}} isn't displayed with whatever is placed in the input field, but rather "{{name}}" is displayed.

Am I incorrectly importing angularjs??

My file system currently looks like

> index.html
>
> js -> app.js
>
> node_modules -> angular -> angular.min.js

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: angular needs to be loaded **before** your `app.js`.

Comment: Good grief. Thanks for telling me. I didn't know the ordering of the script loadings was important!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that since you are using node, the node_modules aren't exposed to the public folder or as a static file.

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#usage):

```
http-server [path] [options]

[path] defaults to ./public if the folder exists, and ./ otherwise.
```

Do you have a public folder? If so, then I would guess that's why.

Answer (score 0):

As Claies said above:

angular needs to be loaded before your app.js

```
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js>
```